# Unexpected token error in mat-checkbox angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<div *ngFor="let bellNotification of earlierBellNotifications">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="updateNotificationEventStatus(bellNotification.key, $event)"
      [(ngModel)]="bellNotification.status==='READ'" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="md-18">
      <span class="wd-notification-event-checkbox" i18n>MARK AS READ</span>
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

When trying to load page, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token
>   '=' at column 33 in [bellNotification.status==='READ'=$event] in
>   ng:///AppSharedModule/BellNotificationComponent.html@43:12 ("
>   ][(ngModel)]="bellNotification.status==='READ'" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="md-18">
>       "): ng:///AppSharedModule/BellNotificationComponent.html@43:12

I tried replacing it with a function from typescript, I still get similar error.

I tried replacing it with a value from typescript, it worked, but it cannot be dynamically updated as it just comes from ts and is not dependent on the for loop iterator.

Can somebody help me point out the mistake in the syntax I am using.

I am new to Angular. Reference links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Replace `[(ngModel)]` with `([ngModel])`

Comment: I'll try that. Any specific reason for that?

Comment: Nope nothing wrong with the code that you have posted, I played with it and replace then worked!

Comment: That may be the cause of you are comparing two values and then assign that result to ngModel expresion

Comment: the two way binding [(NgModel)] need a "variable" `[(ngModel)]="variable"` (you say that if the variable is true/false  is checked or not and if you check/uncheck give value to the variable) You can use only `[ngModel]="bellNotification.status==='READ'"` if only need a one way binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional binding in `[(ngModel)]` expression will not work *(I have never used like this)*!

You can use `[checked]` attribute to *`check/uncheck`* the checkbox with the condition like:

```
<div *ngFor="let bellNotification of earlierBellNotifications">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="updateNotificationEventStatus(bellNotification.key, $event)"  
        \/\/\/
      [checked]="bellNotification.status === 'READ'" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="md-18">
      <span class="wd-notification-event-checkbox" i18n>MARK AS READ</span>
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nftpdq-z7e39b)

Comment: you can use [ngModel] too